# Add Descendant Node to Non-Root Parent

Tags: xml, vb.net, linq

Please note i am new to LINQ to XML.

I am now trying to add A node(descendant) TO a Node

eg.

From this:

```
<World>
    <Country Name = "South_Africa"/>
</World>
```

To This:

```
<World>
    <Country Name = "South_Africa">
        <Person Name = "Aiden Strydom"/>
    </Country>
</World>
```

As you can see i am trying to add a Person node to Country,
but i am not succeeding

Code:

```vb
' Load current document.
Dim XMLDoc As XDocument = XDocument.Load("Test.xml")

' Make new XElement based on incoming parameters.
Dim MyElement As XElement = _
    <Person Name=<%= PersonName %>/>

' Find The Node in Question
Dim e As IEnumerable(Of XElement) = From element
                                    In XMLDoc.Root.Elements("Country")
                                    Where element.Attribute("Name").Value = "South_Africa"
                                    Select element
' Add To it
e.FirstOrDefault().AddFirst(MyElement)

' Save changes to disk.
XMLDoc.Save("Test.xml")
```

Comment: The problem was to add a child node to Country = South Africa, but there were no errors, please read below and if there are any further questions i will clarify - Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't specify what the actual issue is, but you appear to be mixing script markup with code:

```
<Person Name=<%= PersonName %>/>
```

As well as not creating the XElement properly.  I'd try this:

```
' Load current document.
Dim XMLDoc As XDocument = XDocument.Load("Test.xml")

' Make new XElement based on incoming parameters.
 Dim MyElement As New XElement("Person")

' Add the name as an attribute
MyElement.Add(New XAttribute("name", PersonName)) ' PersonName is the supplied value

' Find The Node in Question
Dim e As XElement = (From element In XMLDoc.Root.Elements("Country")
                     Where element.Attribute("Name").Value = "South_Africa"
                     Select element).FirstOrDefault()

' Add To it
e.AddFirst(MyElement)

' Save changes to disk.
XMLDoc.Save("Test.xml")
```

This will take the input XML:

```
<World>
    <Country Name = "South_Africa"/>
</World>
```

And generate:

```
<World>
    <Country Name = "South_Africa">
        <Person Name = "Aiden Strydom"/>
    </Country>
</World>
```

Assuming PersonName in the code above = "Aiden Strydom".

Comment: Thank you all for Replying - Just for noting there were no exceptions/errors and i really appologize the problem was that "South_Africa" in the XML file was "South Africa"(without the underscore), and in the Code i was searching for "South_Africa". When  i realized this everything worked great- all i needed was a good night's sleep. Ps Tim thanks i learnt alot from your code, but mine word too once i realized this semantic error. Thanks a ton guys.

Comment: @Aiden - No problem.  Glad you were able to spot your error and learn something from my answer as well. Happy coding! :)

Comment: @Tim I know it's an old answer, but I think it's confusing right at the first line "You didn't specify what the actual issue is, but you appear to be mixing script markup with code". I don't see any problem with the code, it's a standard XML literals, a thing specific to VB. While your answer provides another way, the OP's way is correct too. Only the underscore was extra.